# Calling a constructor with parameters with new []

Tags: c++, constructor, allocation

I'm trying to call a non-default constructor with parameters and I want to make more than one instance. Currently I have,

```
    headPort[i] = new MyList(i, nullptr)[cap]; // initialize all airports from newport[0] to newport[9]
```

and this is throwing errors. headPort is of type MyList **, and cap is 5.

Is there anyway I can initialize multiple instances of my object with using a non-default constructor?

Comment: You can do that easily by using std::vector<MyList>. To use new, you can new MyList[cap] { MyList(i, nullptr), MyList(i, nullptr), MyList(i, nullptr)...} with cap numbers of MyList(i, nullptr) inside the initialization list

Comment: If `cap` is known at run-time only, then you'd need to use placement-new, by which you'd then be reimplementing `std::vector`, thus having no point.

Comment: They won't let us use vector for the project but thank you.